Avoid duplication of code using C token pasters
This is what my #define macro looks like:
#define CUSTOM_COMPARATOR(table, column, a, b)                          \
    do {                                                                \
        const struct db_##table *row1 = a;                              \
        const struct db_##table *row2 = b;                              \
                                                                        \
        /* Insert lot of code here with multiple row->##column usage */ \
        return strcmp(row1->##column->name1, row2->##column->name2);    \
    } while (0)

I have to generate multiple definitions based on different table and column types. These definitions are preprocessed and called in multiple functions:
static int
db_table_sometable_somecolumn_comparator(const void *a, const void *b) {
    CUSTOM_COMPARATOR(sometable, somecolumn, a, b);
}

static int
db_table_someothertable_someothercolumn_comparator(const void *a, const void *b) {
    CUSTOM_COMPARATOR(someothertable, someothercolumn, a, b);
}

Basically I want to avoid the duplication of code inside CUSTOM_COMPARATOR. When I compile this gcc complains that pasting "->" and "somecolumn" does not give a valid preprocessing token which is understandable since -> breaks the token. It works on db_##table because it produces a single token.
Nonetheless, is there any way I can achieve this? I have like 10s of table/columns with just name change but share the same logic mentioned in CUSTOM_COMPARATOR which is also 50 LoC in real.

It surprises me that you have two members, name1 and name2, in the struct db_tablename structure.  I would expect you to use a single name column.

You're right that line hurts to watch. It is indeed just name. I typoed it while trying to rename production code.

Why not #define GENERATE_COMPARATOR(table, column) static int db_table_ ## table ## _ ## column ## _comparator(const void *a, const void *b) { CUSTOM_COMPARATOR(table, column, a, b) }?  That reduces the risk of a mismatch between the function name and the comparator code.

And you might want a #define COMPARATOR_NAME(table, column) db_table_ ## table ## _ ## column ## _comparator to build the comparator name.  You should use that in the definition of GENERATE_COMPARATOR, but you'd also use when generating the name to pass to the sorting code: qsort(rows, number, sizeof(struct db_sometable), COMPARATOR_NAME(sometable, somecolumn)); etc.  You might even worry about the locked in sometable in db_sometable.  You can go mad if you're not careful.

Token pasting should be considered an advanced feature. You can write a great many useful macros without any token pasting.  Where you consider using it, remember that useful token pasting almost always takes the form of joining two pieces together to form an identifier (name).  If the result of your paste isn't intended to be used as an identifier, then it probably isn't a paste you want to perform.

Don't try to paste the column name to make a new token. You can simply do this:
        return strcmp(row1->column->name1, row2->column->name2);

This is accepted by the preprocessor, and expands to, e.g. with gcc -E:
static int
db_table_sometable_somecolumn_comparator(const void *a, const void *b) {
    do { const struct db_sometable *row1 = a; const struct db_sometable *row2 = b; return strcmp(row1->somecolumn->name1, row2->somecolumn->name2); } while (0);
}

static int
db_table_someothertable_someothercolumn_comparator(const void *a, const void *b) {
    do { const struct db_someothertable *row1 = a; const struct db_someothertable *row2 = b; return strcmp(row1->someothercolumn->name1, row2->someothercolumn->name2); } while (0);
}


which is perfectly valid C.

This works. Thank you so much!
